# Android:About the android pad's screen

Tags: android

I have checked the offical site of android and found that the **Android3.0** supported **1024*800 screen**.But I'm not clear about whether its "1024*800" means the `whole screen including the status bar(I mean the bar including BACK keys and can be not hidden.) or the screen without the status bar???`
And if including the status bar,I wanna know what **the exact pixels of the status bar??**
Can anyone tell me about it?
**Thanks in advance!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no guaranteed resolution for tablet screens, even if you restrict it to only 3.0. A manufacturer could technically create a device of virtually any resolution. That said, generally the given resolution of a HoneyComb device includes the status bar on the bottom with the soft keys. Also, I see no mention of 1024x800 on the Android dev site. I could be missing it, but I find that improbable given that 1024x800 is a very uncommon resolution. 1024x600, 1024x768, 1280x800 are all resolutions that are close that are far more popular.

The status bar's pixel height can change depending on density and probably depending on if the manufacturer decided to change it, so I wouldn't count on it being any one size. What are you planning to use this info for? Maybe there's another way of dealing with it without needing to know the height.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I need to know the height of the status bar because I have to write the xml file in exact pixels(like 1024*768).So sometime the status bar will overlay my xml file which is really trouble.

Comment: I can't really imagine too many scenarios where you *have* to layout in exact pixels. In fact, the docs recommend not to use pixel values.